# ExecJS::ProgramError in Pics#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this big problem, 
when I access the URL as `localhost:3000` then I start getting the below error on my browser:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Pics#index
Showing c:/Sites/insta/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml where line #5 raised:
Rails.root: c:/Sites/insta
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__850650643_69736920'
```

application.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html
%head
  %title Insta
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
  = csrf_meta_tags
%body
  -flash.each do |name, msg|
    =content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info"
= yield
```

Comment: Are you using windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows then

```
gem coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

bundle update